# Rest-assured sends cookies with wrong expires date format?

Tags: java, cookies, rest-assured

The `expires` attribute of cookies should be formatted like `Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT` according to the cookie specs.

I am sending cookies with a request using rest-assured, but the expiry date gets formatted like this: `Expires=9/4/18 12:03 PM`

I am using rest-assured's `Cookie.Builder.setExpiryDate()` to create the cookie, which just accepts a java Date object as input.

Is there any way I can urge rest-assured to change the formatting of the expiry date conforming to the cookie specs?

Answer (score 0):

No. because they use the following code

```
final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
                simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                builder.append(COOKIE_ATTRIBUTE_SEPARATOR).append(EXPIRES).append(EQUALS).append(simpleDateFormat.format(expiryDate));
```

So, what you will get is equivalent to this

```
    Date d1 = new Date();
    System.out.println(d1);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(d1));
```

Output would be something like "7/10/19, 5:50 PM".

You can get the value and then format at you end.